# Merge two different array list based on date with angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sorting

I have two different array list with different objects need to create one list based on creationDate.

**ChatMessage :-**

```
[{
    "creationDate": "2016-05-18 09:21:39",
    "creationUser": "#12:41",
    "message": "sssss",
    "userEmail": "miaai.abc@aail.com",
    "userName": "Miaai",
    "userSurname": "dsith",
    "isRead": false,
    "dossierId": "#88:1"
}, {.. so on ..}]
```

**Document List:-**

```
[{
    "name": "Hamlet.abook",
    "title": "Hamlet.abook",
    "inCompleteMetaData": true,
    "creationDate": "2016-05-17 11:25:23",
    "creationUser": "#12:41"
},{so on ...}]
```

**OutPut Will be** Based on creationDate

```
[{
    "name": "Hamlet.abook",
    "title": "Hamlet.abook",
    "inCompleteMetaData": true,
    "creationDate": "2016-05-17 11:25:23",
    "creationUser": "#12:41"
},{
    "creationDate": "2016-05-18 09:21:39",
    "creationUser": "#12:41",
    "message": "sssss",
    "userEmail": "miaai.abc@aail.com",
    "userName": "Miaai",
    "userSurname": "dsith",
    "isRead": false,
    "dossierId": "#88:1"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union in underscorejs http://underscorejs.org/#union

```
_.union([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10], [2, 1]);
=> [1, 2, 3, 101, 10]
```